# Loading more posts on WP site using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have site on WP. And I'm trying to load posts with AJAX. The difference from other such problems is that I have no pagination, the post section is very simple: two posts near and button below. On click on this button to two posts append previous two posts. I tried to write the solution by myself, but I have little expirience in PHP and maybe in it is the problem.

**Post structure:**

```
<div class="row">       

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news-item">
              <div class="news-date">
                <?php the_time($format = 'j F Y'); ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>

          <div class="more-link"><a href="#">Read more></a>
              </div>
```

**JS**

```
    $(function () {

  var posts = 2;
  var posts_offset = 0;

  $("#load-post").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-content/themes/1cka/load-posts.php",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        posts_offset: posts_offset
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $('.news').append(data);
        posts_offset += 2;

      }
    });
  })
});
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['posts_offset']))
{
  $posts_offset = $_GET['posts_offset'];
}

global $post;

// записываем $post во временную переменную $tmp_post
$tmp_post = $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset'=> $posts_offset );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            echo  '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news-item">
              <div class="news-date">
                <?php the_time($format = 'j F Y'); ?>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>'
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; 

$post = $tmp_post;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have an immediate solution but have you seen https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API ? It implements a rest api for most of your wordpress content, you would be able to fetch any additional posts with a simple ajax call